# How does the length property work?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing code that needs to reference `this` inside a prototype, but it cannot be a function. Javascript won't let me do this, but it seems like the `length` property of arrays and strings does this. I know that `length` is built-in, and my code is not, but if I can, how do I implement this?

I tried:

```
String.prototype.prototypeName = (function(aThing){
    //Do whatever I need to do here
})(this);
```

But that references to the global object, because `this` is called outside of the function.

```
String.prototype.prototypeName = function(aThing){
    //Do whatever I need to do here referencing this
};
```

However, that is a function, and I can't have that.

I can't have a function because the user can call the function and use `typeof` on it, and the prototype is supposed to return a string.
For example:

```
String.prototype.reverse = "Put something that is the reversed string (or this)";
console.log("Stuff"); //"ffutS"
console.log("Anything"); //gnihtynA
```

Comment: Use a getter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: "*reference this inside a prototype, but it cannot be a function*", "*the prototype is supposed to return a string*" - what? Please show the expected result of how you'd use the thing you are asking for.

Comment: No, it is impossible to re-implement what `.length` does on arrays.

Comment: You can always bind `this` if you need to, but it sounds like you are trying to solve the wrong problem. [.bind reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: you can use localStorage to set a number that will mirror where "this" is in the length.   Then use that number to call the right string.  Can you post more code?

Comment: Yes, I posted an example, but I think Andy Ray's comment on a getter worked. @andy You could post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Javascript getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) to access a computed property without calling a prototype function. Note this is IE9+ only.